# In .Net and c# DataTable.Select(string, string) method Question

Tags: c#, .net

What if we write filterExpression equal to null or "" ? Will all the rows be selected?

Comment: @Jonathan: +1, I did wonder about saying the same thing but figured it would take just as much effort to say 'yes'...

But I agree with your sentiment completely.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?  With .NET 3.5 and upwards, there's a better solution to your problem...

Comment: @Jonathan -> Yes I did. Just wanted to confirm if I am doing the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe so.

In fact I more than believe so - having looked at Reflector (unfortunately the MSDN topic doesn't say anything about empty expressions) a filter is only applied if the expression is not empty or null.

That said - why bother doing that?  Just iterate over the Rows or call the Select() method.